# Why BigDecimal does not print 0.5000 in java?

Tags: java

I want to print 0.5000 value in java therefor I try [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this purpose but when i divide i get 0.5 with red color.
Can i print 0.5000 using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if not then why and why does 0.5 print in red font?
My code is:

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    Double n = 0.0, p = 0.0, z = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < 0) n++;
        else if(arr[i] > 0) p++;
        else z++;
    }
    n = BigDecimal.valueOf(n/arr.length).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    p = BigDecimal.valueOf(p/arr.length).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    z = BigDecimal.valueOf(z/arr.length).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

    System.err.println(p);  // print:0.5    //(in red font)
    System.out.println(n);  // print:0.3333
    System.out.println(z);  // print:0.1667
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `BigDecimal` here?

Comment: why not *Double*? and first try to understand diff between *System.out* and *System.err*

Comment: The red font is due to you printing to System.err. Your IDE colors it red to emphasize that it has been written to standard error.

Comment: Java usually chooses the smallest representation of a number, so it takes `0.5` and not `0.5000` or any other representation. If you want a specific format, use a formatter, like `NumberFormatter`. `BigDecimal` provides infinite space for decimal values, the primitive values `double` and `float` have limited precision since they are limited to a specific amount of bytes. There is no other difference. Especially `BigDecimal` does not provide formatting methods. You get a red font since you print on `System.err` (error), your IDE uses a red color for this output channel to highlight it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 n = BigDecimal.valueOf(n/arr.length).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

The result of the right hand side is a `double`: and it gets autoboxed to a `Double` to assign it to the left hand side. When you print `n`, you're not printing a `BigDecimal`, but rather a `Double`.

There is no such thing as a `Double` (or a `double`) `0.5000` as distinct from a `Double` (or a `double`) `0.5`. `0.5000 == 0.5`: they are the same value.

Since there is no scale information stored in a `Double` (or a `double`), there is no way of knowing that you want `0.5000` as opposed to `0.5` or `0.500000000.....000`.

If you want to print with a certain number of decimal places, either use a `NumberFormatter` of some flavour, or keep it as a `BigDecimal`.